# Converting a blob to an image in React-native expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, blob

I have a react-native expo app and am trying to retrieve images from my bucket, decrypt them, and show them. I have the encrypted uploading and retrieving and decrypting working. Now I want to show the images.

I have images stored in a bucket, that are encrypted. My encrypting and decrypting looks like this:

```
export function encryptBlob(blob: Blob, masterKey: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event: any) {
      const arrayBuffer = event.target?.result;
      if (!arrayBuffer) {
        reject("Failed to read binary data from blob.");
        return;
      }

      const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      let binaryData = "";
      uint8Array.forEach((byte) => {
        binaryData += String.fromCharCode(byte);
      });

      const strengthenedPassword = getStrengthenedPassword(masterKey);
      const cipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(binaryData, strengthenedPassword, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
      }).toString();

      resolve(cipherText);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
      reject("An error occurred while reading the blob: " + error);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
}
```

```
export function decryptBlob(cipherText: string, contentType : string, masterKey: string): Promise<Blob> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const strengthenedPassword = getStrengthenedPassword(masterKey);
      const decryptedBinary = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, strengthenedPassword).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);

      const byteNumbers = Array.from(decryptedBinary, (char : any) => char.charCodeAt(0));
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: contentType });

      resolve(blob);
    } catch (error) {
      reject("An error occurred during decryption: " + error);
    }
  });
}
```

After I get the file from the bucket, I run the function like this:

```
const decryptedBlob = await decryptBlob(response.content, response.contentType, encryptionKey);
```

When I print this file it looks like this:

```
{"_data":{"blobId":"0a059363-64e4-4b59-9253-be52c5146cda","offset":0,"size":16993323,"type":"application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8","__collector":{}}}
```

I can create an image using new Blob([decryptedBlob], { type: "image/jpeg" }); and then the file looks like this:

```
 {"_data":{"blobId":"00d18f7c-e3ab-43ff-87eb-471397ad0046","offset":0,"size":16993323,"type":"image/jpeg","__collector":{}}}
```

After this I'm stuck on how to display this image. Can I call it directly? Do I have to write it to the file system? Hoping someone has any experience with this.